# PrototypeJS: how to select dynamically created elements?

Tags: ajax, dynamic, prototypejs

The website is using Prototype JS library.

After page loads, it immediately executes Ajax request, which pulls out and displays more elements for the page.

I need to be able to select those dynamically created elements and hide them with `.hide()` method.

I have tried to select and hide them using `document.observe('dom:loaded', function() { $('my-new-dynamic-element').hide(); })`, but this code does not 'see' the dynamic elements.

I saw Prototype has [`.on()`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/on/index.html) method, but I am not sure which Event should I specify in my case? I tried Event 'load', but no success.

I would appreciate any tips how I could solve this problem.

*UPDATE:* I need to accomplish this in the Magento CMS backend, so I cannot, or better - I do not want to modify original Magento javascript codes and ajax request HTML output. So I need to accomplish this by adding extra custom Javascript code which is using PrototypeJS selectors on dynamically published elements. They need to be hidden, and never shown again. I hope there is a simple couple of lines solution for this.

*PS: I am trying to hide some address elements in Magento Admin -> "Create New Order" page, where all the customer contact data is pulled with ajax request after the main page is loaded. But I don't think this information is important for the problem description.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to show them again later, you could add the 'style="display:none"' to whatever creates the HTML you're inserting (the function behind /myurl, in other words), then you can simply show these elements later in a deferred listener, such as the ones created by the on() method.

```
// /myurl => '<input type="text" class="foo" style="display:none">'

// later, in the combined page
document.on('click', '.some-control', function(evt, elm){
  evt.stop();
  $$('.foo').invoke('show');
});
```

That's a fairly broad selector, you could do something much more specific using next and previous or an id selector instead. The point of the on() method is that the contents of its closure are not evaluated until the event happens, so you can rely on everything that matches the selector being found when it is evaluated, whether it was there at page load or was added later.

If you just want to hide the things that are being added to the page, and you want a completely agnostic method, you can try this:

```
document.on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(evt){
  $$('.some-selector-here').each(function(elm){
    if(elm.visible()) elm.hide();
  });
});
```

That will fire each time the page is modified, so you can test and hide things as they are added if they match your inner selector.

Comment: I cannot modify the HTML which is published on the page. And I do not want the elements to be shown again later. I want to implement this using javascript code which is independent from the current javascript loaded on the page (ajax call, etc)

Comment: I accepted the answer because 'DOMSubtreeModified' event was the answer to my question. However in the [DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) it is written: _Warning! The DOMSubtreeModified event type is defined in this specification for reference and completeness, but this specification deprecates the use of this event type._   @Walter - could you comment on this?

Comment: It is deprecated, but still supported in all major browsers. Firefox complains every time I use it, but still accepts it. There are other ways to manage this (timers), but using `MutationObserver`s is the recommended method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

I would execute a `.hide()` inside the Ajax request success callback. If you are creating the elements dynamically you can manipulate them before they are inserted into the DOM.

For instance

```
new Ajax.Request('/myurl',{'onSuccess':function(result){
    var t = new Element('div').update(result.responseText).hide();

    $$('body')[0].insert(t);

});
```

or more complicated, if you only want to hide specific elements in a blob of html. You need to put the blob in an extended Element first. This will hide all `<input>` elements with the class of `address` that are decedents, (within your blob, not the whole DOM).

```
new Ajax.Request('/myurl',{'onSuccess':function(result){
    var t = new Element('div').update(result.responseText);

    t.select('input.address').invoke('hide');

    $$('body')[0].insert(t.innerHTML);

});
```

Comment: I cannot modify the ajax callback function. I need a separate javascript (PrototypeJS) code. I have updated my question.